# Is there a way to make a phone number clickable on an iphone or android phone to make a call in HTML?

Tags: android, html, iphone, webkit, mobile-safari

Is it possible to make a phone number clickable in HTML so that when a user clicks on the number it is called?

Comment: Are you doing the HTML markup or are you trying to use a third party website and extract the phone numbers?

Comment: @sugarynugs Doing HTML markup.

Comment: have you tried mbairds answer?  that looks like what you want but whether it makes Android dial the number...

Comment: Sorry to have been so dense. I didn't realize that your question was about generating the HTML, not about displaying it on the device. I'm going to delete my answer.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<a href="tel:+1-800-555-5555">Call 1-800-555-5555</a>
```

More info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#tel:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966

Comment: Does this work on devices other than Android too? Such as BlackBerry and iPhone? (using each of their default browsers of course)

And additionally what about on a browser like Opera Mini or Opera Mobile?

Comment: Yes, nothing about that is Android specific.  I've tested it on iOS as well as Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect a phone number in iOS with:

```
<i>web_view.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;<i>
```