# Trying to make a phone number clickable in table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a list of my clients in a google fusion table. I need to make it be clickable for iphone, either in the table or in card view (where I can add inline css)

Nothing work so far..
Help!

Comment: Generate links with "tel:<number>" should work. See [this similar question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4572570/549755).

Comment: Tried this already :( doesn't work on iOS. I click on the link and nothing happens. a Long click yields a bubble asking if I want to open java, if I do nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

What kinds of links have you been adding, exactly? We scrub displayed data to avoid security problems and it's possible we are being overzealous.