# Lotus Notes: Add clickable telephone number to mail

Tags: lotus-notes

In lotus notes i have a script agent that auto generate mails and send it.
In the body of these mails i put lots of data among which some telephone numbers that i want they will be clickable from devices. How can i do this ?
Here the code that i use:

```
notebody="People:" & doc.people(0) & chr(10) & Cstr(doc.date(0)) & "Phone Number:"& doc.phone(0)        
Set rtItem = New NotesRichTextItem(Maildoc , "Body" )
Call rtItem.AppendText(notebody)
```

The field that i want will be clickable is doc.phone(0). How can i do ? thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'First, see here: [Answer to 'Is there a way to make a phone number clickable...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572297/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-phone-number-clickable-on-an-iphone-or-android-phone-to)

In order to adapt that answer to a Notes agent that is using the rich text classes to generate a message, you would need to use pass-thru HTML. You can do this simply by surrounding the HTML fragment with '[' and ']' characters.

I.e., something like this:

```
notebody="People:" & doc.people(0) & chr(10) & Cstr(doc.date(0)) & |Phone Number: [<a href="tel:| & doc.phone(0) & |">| & doc.phone(0) & "</a>]"
```

*Note: not tested! I used the | char as the alternate for quotation marks in order to avoid escaping, and I checked carefully for typos, but...*