# How to Write Clickable Telephone Number in Html which is Local Area Number without Country Code

Tags: html

I am trying to find the way to write clickable Telephone Number in one of my websites. The issue is when I click this on my apple device, It adds + in front of 1 and the number is not dialled properly, because it should not be added. Is there any solution to this where the number 13003377274 is dialled as is?

```
  <a href="tel://13003377274">
    <img alt="call" src="https://www.xxx.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/icons8-phone-50-1.png" width="25" height="25"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NIST Telephone Time-of-Day Service 
<a href="tel:+1-303-499-7111">+1 (303) 499-7111</a>
```

you must add country code to specify where to call. and try above code.

know more about tel 
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/

[image]

Comment: The issue is that the number doesn't get called if I add +61 which is my country code because it is a local number which is free. So I am out of my depth finding solution to it, even the telephone reference guide doesn't give a definite answer.

Comment: Nevermind I found the solution. Thank you so much, I must have been adding the Country code wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<a href="tel:+1-800-555-5555">Call 1-800-555-5555</a>
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#tel:

Reference:  [Is there a way to make a phone number clickable on an iphone or android phone to make a call in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572297/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-phone-number-clickable-on-an-iphone-or-android-phone-to)