# Is there an elegant way to make phone numbers clickable on reactive websites?

Tags: html, css

I use some CSS that detects the view port size and displays a phone number as a clickable link if the user is on a phone.  It seems clunky to me although it works well.

The CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 400px) {
  #show-on-mobile { display: block; }  /* show it on small screens */
  #hide-on-mobile { display: none; } 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 2024px) {
  #show-on-mobile  { display: none; }   /* hide it elsewhere */
  #hide-on-mobile  { display: block; }
```

}

The HTML

```
<div id="show-on-mobile">
    <a href="tel:+14109842714">+1 000-000-0000</a>
</div>
<div x-ms-format-detection="none" id="hide-on-mobile">
    +1 000-000-0000
</div>
```

Is there a better, more streamlined solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make a phone number clickable on an iphone or android phone to make a call in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572297/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-phone-number-clickable-on-an-iphone-or-android-phone-to)

Comment: do you want a js solution?

Comment: If there was some quick and easy JQuery function that would be awesome.

Comment: Why do you want this? Could removing the link styling from the link be good enough?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a bit of javascript, you could leave the phone number within the `<a>` tags, and remove the `href` component if the window width is greater than 400px.

HTML:

```
<a href="tel:+14109842714">+1 000-000-0000</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function(){
    if ( window.innerWidth > 400 ) {
        document.querySelector('[href="tel:+14109842714"]').href = '';
    }
};
```

CSSTricks hs a great little article on this: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-disable-links/